# Passing multiple positional shell arguments to java application

Tags: java, linux, shell

I programmed a Java app. For complex reasons I cannot export it as an executable (due to CVS and environment promoting practices) to Linux. I also cannot add the main class path to the MANIFEST.MF via 'jar -cvmf' command because it is not installed in the Linux environment the app is running in (I have no control over what gets installed). The only other option I found was to create the following shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#check that parameters were passed
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo ""
    echo "Not enough arguments provided. You must have at least 2 arguments with ISO SQL time stamps."
    echo " After that you can have unlimited number of parameters for tools."
    echo ""
    exit 1  
fi 

echo "Recovering events that occurred between $@"

ROOT_DIR=_spool_generator
JAR_DIR=jar
mkdir $ROOT_DIR
mkdir $ROOT_DIR/$JAR_DIR

FULL_DIR=$ROOT_DIR/$JAR_DIR

cp /home/wma/jar/SpoolGenerator.jar ./$FULL_DIR/

echo $@

START=$1
END=$2

java -cp "./$FULL_DIR/SpoolGenerator.jar" com.btv.main.Driver $@ # --> does not work
#java -cp "./$FULL_DIR/SpoolGenerator.jar" com.btv.main.Driver "2001-02-12 18:15:00.0" "2001-02-12 19:15:00.0"  --> works
#java -cp "./$FULL_DIR/SpoolGenerator.jar" com.btv.main.Driver  "$START" "$END" --> works

echo "Execution is complete..."

exit
```

The key issue here is that I have an unlimited number of parameters the application uses. This works great when deploying the java app directly as an executable in Windows, works fine if I specify the positional arguments the Shell script takes, but how do I pass these same arguments to the java app from within the Linux script. I have to pass the parameters to the script surrounded in quotes due to the timstamp's special characters, this seems to cause some aberrant parsing when the parameters are passed to the jar. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Quote your variable expansions like `"$@"`. Shellcheck warns about these things

Comment: Actually, looks like that worked. I could have sworn I had tried that but maybe I got mixed up in the way I was specifying the arguments. Thanks. I'll check Shellcheck in the future too.